# Does ServletRequest.setAttribute permit key names with periods?

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1, servlets

I have a java webapp with a Struts 1 action that has the following code:

```
request.setAttribute("cat.sound", "meow");
```

On my jsp page, I have the following tag:

```
<c:out value="${cat.sound}" />
```

However, "meow" is never printed on the JSP page. This might work if I had an object of type "cat" to do something like:

```
request.setAttribute("cat", cat);
```

Unfortunately, this webapp does not have any object defined for the cats and the jsp pages are frozen (no changes allowed).

So is it possible to use request.setAttribute with a key name containing periods/dots? How would the JSP page need to reference the set parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid having to create a `Cat` class if you set `cat` to a map with a String key `"sound"`:

```
request.setAttribute("cat", Collections.singletonMap("sound", "meow"));
```

[`Collections#singletonMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap%28K%2C%20V%29) gives you a nice, succinct way to create a map with one entry.